# Is there any requirements on the number of indicator variables? and Reliability test?

Tags: structural-equation-modeling

Hello I am learning to perform structural equation modeling analysis, attached is the proposed model. 1. Am allowed to only one indicator variables (observed variable, exogenous) (a1) for variable A. I found most of the models I read from the literature all have over 2 indicator variables(observed) for each latent variable, some of them even did reliability analysis.
2. Could variables E and F be category data?

As I am still learning this analysis, please forgive me if I used incorrect nouns. Thanks.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's 'allowed', but why bother.  In the days of the original LISREL language you had to do this. But with modern programs (and even Lisrel) you can just put a1 in, in the place of A.

E and F can be binary.